# Preventing Commands from Being Shown Batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I just installed MinGW on my Windows 10 computer and set up a sample program so that I could test if it was working. I used a batch file so that I could keep the program going with `pause`. However, while testing this I got this: [Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKire.png)

I only want the output to be shown, not the commands needed to execute it. How do I do that?

Comment: Your script is asking for input, so what do you want to see on your screen?

Comment: @music2myear That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `echo off` command. To prevent echoing commands to the screen, use this, typically as the first line of your batch script.

```
echo off
```

However, that line itself will be echoed, because the echoing is not turned off until the line is processed. To prevent even that line from displaying, use this as your first line:

```
@echo off
```

The `@` means "do not display this line". So it suppresses the display of the `echo off` line, which then in turn suppresses the display of future lines.

If you want to turn it back on later:

```
echo on
```